# TypeScript can't find npm module with included .d.ts typings (webpack with ts-loader)

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, typescript-typings, konvajs

I'm trying to import the [Konva](https://www.npmjs.com/package/konva) library into my TypeScript+webpack project, but the compiler can't find the module without pointing it directly into `node_modules`.

There is no DefinitelyTyped package for Konva, the `.d.ts` file is already included in the npm package. I can import [another](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js) npm package that *does* have a DefinitelyTyped entry in the way I'd expect.

I tried adding `.d.ts` to my `resolve.extentions` in `webpack.config.js`, but that didn't help either. I found [these](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/91) [issues](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/144) on their [github](https://github.com/konvajs/konva), but both have been marked as closed.

#### Directory structure

```
node_modules/
    '-- @types/
        '-- tesseract.js/
            '-- index.d.ts
            '-- package.json
            '-- types-metadata.json
    '-- konva/
        '-- src/
        '-- konva.d.ts
        '-- konva.js
        '-- konva.min.js
        '-- package.json
    '-- tesseract.js/
        '-- dist/
        '-- src/
        '-- package.json
src/
    '-- index.ts
package.json
package-lock.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

The only notable difference I could find was that Konva doesn't have a `types-metadata.json` file. Could this be the issue? I couldn't find any documentation on this file.

#### index.ts

```
import * as Konva from 'konva' //this errors
import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'; //this works fine
//import * as Konva from '../node_modules/konva/konva' this 'works' too
...
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```

#### package.json

```json
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3",
        "webpack": "^4.29.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/tesseract.js": "0.0.2", //this library is working perfectly
        "tesseract.js": "^1.0.14"
        "konva": "^2.6.0", //this one isn't
    }
    ...
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,

    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "sourceMap": true,

        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,

        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the module resolution to your tsconfig.json _"module": "commonjs"_ or any other module system you are using.
They have d.ts in their module.

Comment: @joseph-climber This solved my issue, but it broke my `file-loader` imports. I solved this by using `"esModuleInterop": true` in my `tsconfig.json`, but that broke the `import * as ... from ...` statement I had for the Tesseract module. This too I could solve, by using a default import (`import ... from ...`).
Strangely enough the Konva library's 'start import' did not rise any errors, and continued to work perfectly. I should probably create an issue for this at the `ts-loader` respository, but it works fine for now. Thank you for your help, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: And that would be the wrong answer(kinda). Turns out -  :-)  - that what i'd refer as _module resolution_ is in fact the module code generation option and using modules system other than commonjs would require to specify the file name not just the module folder name.